# Tomato growth in different systems

Tags: science-based, cities, food

I am an architecture student, currently working on my master thesis on the topic of urban farming. I am not doing a research on tomato production in order to determine what system would be the best and give the best results in a city(closed) environment. I would like to compare soil, hydroponic and aeroponics system. So far I have found the data for soil and hydro while the information for aeroponics is harder to find so I need your help. So far I was able to calculate:
soil: tomato yield of 6kg per plant 69tonnes/Ha and around 11000 plants/Ha
hydroponics: tomato yield 25kg per plant 585tonnes/Ha and around 22000 plants/Ha
So if anyone knows where can I find the data for aeroponics or if I made bad calculations please let me know because it would be a great help! Thanks

Comment: Hi Miloc, I'm not quite sure what you are asking or how it's relevant to worldbuilding.

Comment: I am imagining a future scenario a future city, where the food would only be grown within city limits. So what would be done and what system would be used to produce food in closed environment, neglecting traditional soil method, and to find the best solution i am doing a case study of tomatoes and trying to see how this would will be shaped.

Comment: There is certainly a question that could be on topic there. I think you need to be clearer about what you have worked out so far and how you got there (i.e. sources, methods etc) if you want people to check your results. Asking for sources of aeropnics data isn't really on topic here (and would make this two questions instead of one) but if you wanted to ask a second question about aeropinically grown tomatos that would be fine.